# Execute permission on files in Azure webjob

Tags: pdf-generation, azure-webjobs

I'm using the library http://www.hiqpdf.com/

When using it in an Azure Webjob, I get the exception: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: Conversion failed. Check HiQPdf.dep was copied in the same folder with HiQPdf.dll library. Check HiQPdf.dep has read and execute permissions"

Is it even possible to have execute permissions in an Azure webjob?

Answer (score 0):

azure web jobs and websites have limited execution privileges despite having 'full trust' see this doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-available-operating-system-functionality

when trying to make pdf the recommended lib as far as i know is: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

it is used in an msdn article showing how to do pdf generation in a web job here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707529.aspx